# Implementar plantillas en formato PDF en java swing

Tags: java, java-swing, pdf

Tengo el siguiente requerimiento:

> El Analista dispone de un conjunto de documentos modelo de constancias
> (plantillas). Una plantilla para cada tipo de constancia.
>
> Estas plantillas cuentan con campos donde se insertan datos variables,
> como la fecha, nombre y apellido del estudiante, nombre del evento,
> etc.
>
> Las plantillas de constancias que se están utilizando actualmente se
> adjuntan a este documento.
>
> El sistema habilita la edición de las plantillas (modelo de documento)
> de los distintos tipos de Constancias como un campo extenso de texto,
> donde los campos para los datos variables se delimitan por &...&
>
> Por ejemplo: “Se deja constancia que el estudiante &apellido&,
> &nombre& con ci &cedula& ha aprobado el curso de &curso&.”
>
> El sistema debe contar con la opción de descargar, generando un
> archivo en formato pdf.

¿Cómo podría implementar esto utilizando Java Swing?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Te recomiendo [JasperReports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).

Answer (score 1):

No es posible hacerlo solamente con swing, es mas.. Swing ni siquiera tiene un visor de PDF incluido.

No es posible ya que esta libreria es una libreria de compatibilidad de componentes visuales, su fuerte es la portabilidad de interfaces graficas, no te sirve para leer archivos, no te sirve para escribir archivos, no te sirve para calcular dimensiones de fuentes o la forma en que un color se ve impreso, detectar impresoras y su configuracion (como distintas dimensiones de hojas y orientaciones), etc.

Para eso existe otra libreria llamda [java-awt](/questions/tagged/java-awt), la mayoria de librerias para generacion de pdfs tanto libres como d epaga hechas en java usan AWT.

Como lo que te piden no es hacer tu propia plantilla te recomiendo usar alguna de esas librerias ya que implementar por tu cuenta la lectura/escritura de archivos que cumplan con los estandares del formato pdf no es una tarea trivial